# How to place the cursor into a specific textbox in dynamics crm using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm

How can I place the cursor when an option is selected like `Existing Product` from the two option then the cursor should be placed into the `Existing Product box`. How can I do this using JavaScript in dynamics crm 2011?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the **setFocus** method of the Xrm... object hierarchy. See [here for details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334266.aspx#BKMK_setFocus)

Comment: thnx keerz for reply i have done this in the following manner, but this give me the error that the object doesn't have the property or method "setFocus()"
 
   var v =  Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("new_male");
   v.setFocus();

Comment: @user2384794 you set focus to the control, not the attribute. try var control = Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get(“AttributeName”);
control.setFocus(); see [here](http://crmbusiness.wordpress.com/2011/05/19/crm-2011-how-to-set-focus-using-javascript/)